# iTerm how to show full path on the title bar of the splitted panes

Tags: iterm2

I am using `iTerm2`. From Profile => General => Basics => Title: `Session Name` and `PWD` is selected.

Afterwards I ssh into a remote machine. Title bar of the splitted panes does not show the full path of the directory of the remove machine.

[image]

Instead it only shows the end portion of it with `...` at the beginning. Would it be possible to see the full path or expand its length?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the path is long enough, it is ellipsized in the title.

Turn-off the prefix truncation in  **Preferences** -> **Advanced** section -> **Use 'smart truncation' for tab titles**. But if the `pwd` is long, suffix is still truncated. So

1. Increase Tab title size.

Goto **Preferences** -> **Advanced** -> **Tabs** ->
Change size in *Minimum tab width when using uneven tabs* or *Preferred tab width when tabs are equally sized.*

2. Use **Badges**, alternate option

Goto **Preferences** -> Select **profile** -> **General** -> **Basics**-> Enter `\(tab.currentSession.path)` in the Badge text box. Current `pwd` will appear like this.

[image: iterm2 Badges]

While this answer is written, couldn't find an option to set tab title width apt to the title length. May be available in future.

Comment: I set width size to 250, but now it still show like `../end/foo` -- `/Users/home/path`. so basically I ssh into a remote machine. left part (`Title: Session Name`) (pwd of the remote machine shown with `...`) but right side `PWD` which is my local machine shown as full path.